# My stub always return null value mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In the below code I am trying to mock an EmailService class and stub method send message1 with some value but it always returns null value

```
package com;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestFile {

    private FacebookService facebookService;

    @Mock
    private EmailService mockedEmailService;

    @Before
    public  void setUp() {
        EmailService emailService = mock(EmailService.class);
        when(emailService.sendMessage1("1","1")).thenReturn("dfdfgdfg");
         facebookService = new FacebookService(emailService);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMessage() {
        String actualResult = facebookService.sendMessage("msg", "recepient");
        System.out.println(actualResult);
    }
}
```

**FacebookService**

```
public class FacebookService implements MessageService {

    @SuppressWarnings("emailService")
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Inject
    FacebookService(EmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    public String sendMessage(String msg, String receipient) {
        // some complex code to send Facebook message
        emailService.sendMessage1("A", "B");
        System.out.println("Message sent to Facebook user " + receipient + " with message=" + msg);
        return ("Debbie" + emailService.sendMessage1("", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: please stop adding code in the comments, use the [edit] functionality.

Comment: Your actual implementation of `sendMessage(msg, recipient)` makes no sense.
You don't pass the parameters to emailService.
You hardcode them with magical constant values. Really not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You currently only match / stub calls to `sendMessage1("1","1")` but invoke it via `sendMessage1("A","B")` or `sendMessage1("","")`, probably you should do:

```
when(emailService.sendMessage1(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("dfdfgdfg");
```

You need to import https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString() for that.

Comment: It did not help. When we stub we can pass any values to arguments I suppose.

Comment: @DeepakMehra When it doesn't help, then something is wrong in your setup. You mocked a EmailService object. You pass that to your class under test. You invoke the method under test that should call your mock. All of that looks correct. In that sense: improve your question to *really* contain a full [mcve]!